# Translation of "mind you" in French

Tags: traduction, anglais, oral

> His advice wasn't very helpful. I'm not criticizing him, mind you.
>
> The fact remains, mind you, that the second album, The Least We Can Do Is Wave to Each Other, is far superior.

How can we render “mind you” in the sense of

> informal —used in speech to give stress to a statement that one is
> making so that a preceding or following statement will not be
> misunderstood. [Reference](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mind%20you)

Here are the corresponding French sentences I am thinking about.

> Ses conseils n'étaient pas très utiles. Je ne le critique pas, remarquez.
>
> Il n'en reste pas moins, remarquez, que le deuxième album est de loin supérieur.

Are they really idiomatic?

Comment: maybe "ceci dit" would fit, at least this is how I would fill the two senstences in French, but I am not sure of the sense of "mind you" in English.

Comment: @radouxju or better: [*cela dit*](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/pierre-g-rennes)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*"mind you"* est ce que l'on appelle un *idiotisme*. C'est donc à dire, pour reprendre l'opinion de Balzac : intraduisible.

Selon le contexte, familier ou non, à l'écrit ou à l'oral, pour ce qui est de la première phrase je dirai parfois :

- *Note(z) que* antéposé : Notez que je ne le critique pas.
- *Note(z) [bien / le]* postposé : Je ne le critique pas, notez [bien / le]
- *Attention (hein!)* : Attention hein! Je ne le critique pas.

La seconde phrase se prête moins (pour moi) aux tournures ci-dessus car le locuteur prononce un jugement de valeur sur un fait. Nul besoin (à mon opinion) d'insister.
Si on y tient absolument alors, (peut-être parce qu'il est prononcé en opposition avec des propos précédents et que c'est sur cette opposition que je veux attirer l'attention ou si je veux faire mon interlocuteur complice) j'opterais pour :

- *Le fait reste, vois-tu, que le deuxième album...* ou encore :
- *Le fait reste, comme tu le vois, que le deuxième...*

Answer (score 1):

Il m'est impossible de formuler une opinion sur ces formes particulières; je peux seulement assurer que certaines formes,  qui fournissent une traduction pour « mind you », sont idiomatiques.

Il existe un choix alternatif de verbe, le verbe « noter », mais il semble que l'on ne l'emploierait pas à la fin et de ce fait il devient incertain que la fin soit une place aussi bonne qu'une autre pour « remarquez ».

Il me semble que la forme suivante serait non idiomatique;

```
Ses conseils n'étaient pas très utiles. Je ne le critique pas, notez.
```

Il n'y a cependant aucun doute à propos des suivantes, elles sont idiomatiques et correspondent à l'original anglais.

> Ses conseils n'étaient pas très utiles. Notez bien, je ne le critique pas. 
>   Ses conseils n'étaient pas très utiles. Notez (bien) que je ne le critique pas.

Je peux assurer comme étant idiomatiques les formes suivantes;

> Ses conseils n'étaient pas très utiles. Remarquez (bien) que je ne le critique pas.
>   Ses conseils n'étaient pas très utiles. Remarquez (bien), je ne le critique pas.
>
> Il n'en reste pas moins, remarquez (bien), que le deuxième album est de loin supérieur.
>     Il n'en reste pas moins, notez (bien), que le deuxième album est de loin supérieur.